# Installing of solartherm

Tags: msys2, openmodelica

I am using this guideline to install solartherm: https://github.com/SolarTherm/SolarTherm/wiki/Running-SolarTherm-on-Windows-%28MSYS2%29
I reach the point where I need to install Dakota and I get this error:

```
-bash: unzip: command not found
cp: cannot stat 'dakota-6.14.0.Windows.x64/*': No such file or director
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error message there is telling you that `unzip` does not exist.  That command comes from a file (`/usr/bin/unzip.exe`) that is provided by an MSYS2 package named `unzip`.  So you need to install that package by running `pacman -S unzip` and then try again.

Note that the wiki page you linked to *already told you to install the unzip package* so I recommend that you go back to the beginning of the instructions and double check all of them to make sure you are on the right track.  Pay attention to any error messages you receive along the way.